# Parallel copy to move large amount of Data in linux

Tags: linux, shell, rsync

I have folder which needs to be migrated to NFS location and its around 20T. when I try to rsync(or using parallel rsync) its taking lot of time. even with parallel rsync. is there any way we can improve copy rate? I just want to move entire directory even no need of syncing:

Tried the following option but with this its taking very long:

```
rsync -avzm --stats --safe-links --ignore-existing --dry-run --human-readable /<dir>/ /<nfs path> > /tmp/sync.log

/tmp/sync.log | parallel --will-cite -j 5 rsync -avzm --relative --stats --safe-links --ignore-existing --human-readable {} /<nfs path (dest dir)> > /tmp/result.log
```

I think its overwriting and taking lot than regular.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using Linux or running Linux commands. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Generally I/O transfer is the bottleneck. You can only read and write so fast which is usually a limit of the hard disk with a theoretical limit of about 120M/s (SATA 3). If you have a 20T SSD (doubtful) then the bottleneck will still be the drive or perhaps the bus the drive is on. In either case it doesn't matter if you have 20 processes that try and write the 20T of data in parallel or 1 process moving all data -- the time it takes will still be limited by I/O.